# How to apply filter in separate tables in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to apply a filter on two separate tables, but the problem is when I use the filter in only one and then I select the other one and click on the filter the filter button is deactivated, so I can apply the filter only to a table. How do I insert the filter into the two tables ?? without needing to format as table or PivotTable,?[image]

Answer (score 1):

**This VBA (Macro) code will help you to Filter two tables one by one on different Criteria.**

**Unfiltered Tables:**

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If CommandButton1.Caption = "Filter Table1" Then

 With Sheet2

 .AutoFilterMode = False
 .Range("A210:D222").AutoFilter
 .Range("A210:D222").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Albama"

End With
CommandButton1.Caption = "Filter Table2"

ElseIf CommandButton1.Caption = "Filter Table2" Then

With Sheet2

 .AutoFilterMode = False
 .Range("A225:D237").AutoFilter
 .Range("A225:D237").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Portor"

End With
CommandButton1.Caption = "Filter Table1"
End If

End Sub
```

**Filter 1st Table:**

[image]

**Filter 2nd Table:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Create one Command button & Set Caption 
  **Filter Table1**.
- **Click** on Command Button to open VB editor 
  and **Copy & Paste** above shown code as 
  Standard Module.
- **Save** and Return to Sheet.
- **Click** on Command Button to **Filter Table 
  1**, after that Code will set it's **Caption, 
  Filter Table2**.
- Then **Click** on Command Button to **Filter 
  Table2**, after that Code will set it's 
  **Caption, Filter Table1**.

*In this way you can Filter both Tables one after another.*

**N.B.**

- In above show code **Sheet Name, Range, Field & 
  Criteria** are editable.
- If you want to use more than one criteria then 
  your code should like this,

  `.Range("A210:D222").AutoFilter Field:=1, 
    Criteria1:="Albama", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="Verginia"`
- For more than one Field:

  `.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Albama"
  .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Portor"`

*Adjust Cell references in the Code as needed.*

Comment: want to apply the filter at the same time in the two tables as different values, are different tables from each other, wanted to filter different tables, I need 2 filters at a time without interfering in both

Comment: I want to create a filter in both, to filter separately and not just one! When you click on the filter you can not deactivate the filter of the first table, it is necessary to activate the filter of the first and second at the same time

Comment: Is there any way?

Comment: I changed the tables, they are not sharing the same line, they are in different places. Now the tables do not have the same values ​​shown in the image above, they are different, get it?

Comment: @ElienayJunior,, it doesn't matters whether Tables are similar or different the Same VBA code will Filter Data from both,, what you need is to change the Field & Criteria as I've also mentioned in my post,, check the **N.B**. part !

Answer (score 0):

You would need to select the range occupied by **both** tables before applying the first filter - this will display filter buttons across **all** columns in the selected range (including the blank columns between the two tables, but this is unavoidable):

[image]

The above is assuming that you do not want to convert the two ranges to separate tables; if you did, you could filter the two tables separately.

Comment: Yes, but in this case you did, it will apply the filter on both tables and both tables will change at the same time. And if by chance I separated the tables so they would be filtered separately, would it have any way ??

Comment: I want to filter the tables separately without changing the other

Comment: This is not possible, as the two tables share rows - I would suggest moving one of your tables to a separate worksheet.

Comment: @ElienayJunior,, if you want to filter a Table without changing another then you need to apply Filter on one Table only at the time!

Comment: @Rajesh S,, I wanted to distribute the filter in the two tables, with specific changes in each of them

Comment: @ElienayJunior, in case of Auto Filter , Excel doesn't allows to select two Tables/Data Range where both are either side by side or below each other, but for this you may use Advance Filter. And if  filtered data need to be filter further data from another Table then you need an Array Command.

Comment: **Continue,,,** attached Screen shot has got similar data in both Tables therefore is useless to apply filter on both,,,,!!

Comment: @Rajesh S, And even though the tables are different, the filter only applies to one table at a time. I was wanting some formula or VBA code to apply the filter to more than one table

Comment: @Rajesh S, Do you know any VBA code or formula to apply the filter in both tables and filter different criteria?

Comment: @ElienayJunior You can filter both tables with different criteria using the method I have described in my answer above, however, **filtering one table will necessarily affect the other since they share the same rows.**

Comment: @ElienayJunior,, yes I can,, just check my post below the VBA code Filter 2 Tables one by one on different Criteria.